# CMake (cmake-gui) silently crashes on Windows 10

Tags: cmake, installation, execution, cmake-gui

After months of working correctly I've found that running CMake in GUI form on Windows 10 suddenly began silently crashing on every launch. It does not appear to be the fault of a recent Windows update given an associate of mine has experienced the same issue in an older version of Windows 10.

I installed CMake 3.15.0-rc4 as well as the stable 3.14.6 release, uninstalled, and reinstalled them to no success. The same issue persists in launching Windows in safe mode, and still persists after performing registry fixes.

Resetting my Windows 10 solved the problem at least for now.

Have you experienced this issue, and if so what is a solution that doesn't involve resetting the Windows 10 OS installation?